# DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

Why is this exception being triggered with a fresh new project?

---

Instructions:

- Run `flutter create ./app_sample && cd ./app_sample`
- Run `flutter pub add firebase_core`
- Run `flutter build ios`

Exceptions:

- Error (Xcode): `DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead`

Console output:

```
user@host % flutter create ./app_sample && cd ./app_sample
Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "Apple Development: JOHN DOE
(...)"
Creating project app_sample...
Resolving dependencies in app_sample... 
Got dependencies in app_sample.
Wrote 129 files.

All done!
You can find general documentation for Flutter at: https://docs.flutter.dev/
Detailed API documentation is available at: https://api.flutter.dev/
If you prefer video documentation, consider: https://www.youtube.com/c/flutterdev

In order to run your application, type:

  $ cd app_sample
  $ flutter run

Your application code is in app_sample/lib/main.dart.

user@host app_sample % flutter pub add firebase_core
Resolving dependencies... 
  collection 1.17.2 (1.18.0 available)
+ firebase_core 2.17.0
+ firebase_core_platform_interface 4.8.0
+ firebase_core_web 2.8.0
+ flutter_web_plugins 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
+ js 0.6.7
  material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
  meta 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
+ plugin_platform_interface 2.1.6
  stack_trace 1.11.0 (1.11.1 available)
  stream_channel 2.1.1 (2.1.2 available)
  test_api 0.6.0 (0.6.1 available)
  web 0.1.4-beta (0.2.2-beta available)
Changed 6 dependencies!
user@host app_sample % flutter build ios
Building com.example.appSample for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project:
NDB72348L6
Running pod install...                                             967ms
Upgrading Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig
Upgrading Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig
Upgrading Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            5.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR
instead


Encountered error while building for device.
user@host app_sample %
```

Versions:

- Flutter: 3.13.6
- Xcode: 15.0
- macOS: 14.0

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by modifying Podfile. However, am I gonna have to do this for every new project?

./ios/Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
    xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
    xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
    File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
    end
  end
end
```